# How to print the link of a category into the href="" of an anchor tag in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

Ok so in my header.php file of my wordpress theme I have a navigation bar as shown below.

```
<nav>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="Design">Design</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="Tech">Tech</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="Photography">Photography</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="Film">Film</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="Gaming">Gaming</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="Motion">Motion</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="Lifestyle">Lifestyle</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="Coding">Coding</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="Business">Business</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="Other">Other</a>
</nav>
```

What I want to do is have a wordpress code that inserts the link to the page containing a list of all the categorys, in my case with the current permalink setup mine looks like this "www.example.com/design/post-name" so I essentially want it to link to "www.example.com/design" when the code is inserted into the anchor tag as shown below.

```
    <a href="<?php code I want goes here ?>" class="nav-link" id="Design">Design</a>
```

Any help is appreciated!  :)

- Jamie

Comment: You might want to start with a for loop in php. then grabbing data from your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the category object and then use a foreach loop to build your list.

This should work for you:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(); ?>
<nav>
  <?php foreach ($categories as $category):?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id); ?>" class="nav-link" id="<?php echo $category->name;?>"><?php echo $category->name;?></a>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks.  Do you know how I could display them in a custom order instead of the links being in alphabetical order?

Comment: Also, you can reorder categories using the category and taxonomy order plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/